# Create OpenGL textures using Eigen

Tags: textures, eigen, opengl-3

A single channel R32F texture can be created quite easily (and safely) in Eigen:

```
    glGenTextures(1, &_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int rows = 480, cols = 640;
    static Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> A(rows,cols);
    A.setConstant(rows, cols, 0.0f);
    for(int row=0; row<A.rows(); row++)
        for(int col=0; col<A.cols(); col++)
            A(row,col) = .5f + .5*sin( 10* /*period*/ 2*3.14*row/A.rows() );
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, cols, rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, A.data());
```

The code above generates this image: [image: striped along columns]

A similar approach can be used to generate RGB32F textures:

```
    glGenTextures(1, &_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int rows = 480;
    int cols = 640;
    static Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Vector3f, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> A(rows,cols);
    for(int row=0; row<A.rows(); row++)
        for(int col=0; col<A.cols(); col++)
            A(row,col) = vec3(row/((float)A.rows()), col/((float)A.cols()), 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, cols, rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, A.data());
```

The code above generates this image: [image: quad colored according to x and y]:

Everything seems to work well on my machine, however, **can this procedure result in any problem?** especially considering what is mentioned in the Eigen documentation:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#user_defined_scalars

Answer (score 4):

As Avi said, such use case is perfectly fine.

For the fun, here are loop-less versions:

```
Array<float,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> A;
A.colwise() = 0.5f + 0.5*sin(ArrayXf::LinSpaced(rows,0,10*2*3.14));
```

and:

```
Array<Array3f,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> A(rows,cols);
A.block(0,0,rows,cols) = A.NullaryExpr(rows, cols, [&] (long i, long j) { return Array3f(float(i)/float(rows), float(j)/float(cols), 0); });
```

The second one can also be achieved through some setup to get a view for each channel:

```
typedef Array<float,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> RowArrayXXf;
typedef Map<RowArrayXXf,0,Stride<Dynamic,3> > Channel;
Channel A_red(  A.data()->data()+0, rows, cols, Stride<Dynamic,3>(3*cols,3));
Channel A_green(A.data()->data()+1, rows, cols, Stride<Dynamic,3>(3*cols,3));
Channel A_blue( A.data()->data()+2, rows, cols, Stride<Dynamic,3>(3*cols,3));
```

and then, you get all the power of Eigen's API to work on individual channels:

```
A_red.colwise() = ArrayXf::LinSpaced(rows,0,1);
A_green.rowwise() = ArrayXf::LinSpaced(cols,0,1).transpose();
A_blue.setZero();
```

In your case that's overkill, but might be useful to perform more complicated operation, or to write a small wrapper around `Array<Array3f>` for images.

Comment: I see you use "Array" rather than a matrix. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because `Array` is more suited to store a collection of numbers onto which we want to work coefficient-wise. For instance, `sin(Array<>)` applies the sine coefficient-wise, whereas `sin(Matrix<>)` would means the matrix operator sine.

Answer (score 2):

It is all fine and legal. However, there may (sometimes) be some issues. In your case, all you did with `A(i,j)` was assign. When attempting to use arithmetic operations, some issues sometimes arise (e.g. [subtracting a `Vector3d` from the entire matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32277887/2899559)). You may not run into any such issues, depending on your use.